# Mongoose: Invalid value for schema Array path, got value "undefined"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have the following probelm that elements is undefined when make it equal to a Schema. the element courses in Course.js is undefined.

User.js file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

let Course = require(__dirname + "/Course.js");
let Tutor = require(__dirname + "/Tutor.js");

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

console.log(Course.courseSchema)

var userSchema = new Schema ({
  name: String,
  email: String,
  username: String,
  password: String,
  courses: [Course.courseSchema],
  tutors: [Tutor.tutorSchema],
  isTutor: Boolean,
  subscribed: Boolean,
  googleId: String,
  facebookId: String
});


let User = mongoose.model("User", userSchema);


module.exports = {
  userSchema: userSchema,
  User: User
}
```

Course.js file:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let Tutor = require(__dirname + "/Tutor.js");
let Category = require(__dirname + "/Category.js");
let Module = require(__dirname + "/Module.js");
let User = require(__dirname + "/User.js" );
let CourseReview = require(__dirname + "/CourseReview.js");

var courseSchema = new Schema ({
  title: String,
  categories: [Category.categorySchema],
  tags: [String],
  shortDescription: String,
  students: [User.userSchema],
  language: [String],
  tutor: [Tutor.tutorSchema],
  requirement: String,
  description: String,
  module: [Module.moduleSchema],
  reviews: [CourseReview.courseReviewSchema]
});

let Course = mongoose.model("Course", courseSchema);

module.exports = {
  courseSchema: courseSchema,
  Course: Course
}
```

dbs file strcuture:

```
dbs
├── Course.js
├── User.js
```

Im getting back "TypeError: Invalid value for schema Array path `courses`, got value "undefined". I'be been trying to fix the directory but the Schema cant be recognized and I ghave read the subdocument documentation that allow you to call the schema in another Schema. Does anybody know how to fix this?

Answer (score 5):

You've got circular dependency between `User` and `Courses` module. As simple as that - [more on this particular issue.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10869276/how-to-deal-with-cyclic-dependencies-in-node-js) that's why `Course.courseSchema` is undefined while loading `User.js`.

Additionally, your schema doesn't make practical sense. You probably want to reference these users, courses, tutors by some kind of identifiers thus creating relations. You don't want `user.courses` contain `Course` which again contain instance of `user` and so on.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34985846/mongoose-document-references-with-a-one-to-many-relationship) for description how to create relationships in mongoose.

Comment: Thank for your advice, it actually helps me to restructure my database again to avoid circular dependency